# Ubuntu Cordova app creation

Tags: cordova

I have installed cordova on my system(Ubuntu), is fine. But when i try to create app using this command

`cordova create hello com.example.hello "Hello World"`

I got this error:

```
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
```

Why is this error happened?